# Internal error during install MySQL: Value cannot be null. Parameter name : path 1,

Tags: mysql

I'm new in mysql user .
At first I install MySQL version 5.6.26.0 in my windows 10.
But after complete installation I didn't see any GUI in MySQL workbench.
So I uninstall all MySQL program and tried to install newly.

But now MySQL installer give me an error 
"Internal error (Value cannot be null. Parameter name : path 1) The installer will now close."

How can I solve this problem ?

Any help will be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: At last I would able to solve my problem. Now everything works perfectly.

At first my when I install MySQL there were some problem, that was Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribution Package was not install in my pc, 
though it says that it'll be install automatically but it didn't.
That's why I didn't find any MySQL Workbench .

Next while I uninstall all MySQL program but some files in local user in App data still remains, that create obstacle in my new installation.

Comment: But I didn't know what was those files. So I didn't delete those files manually.
That's why again I uninstall all MySQL program by using some uninstaller and also delete all shared,detected files included those programs which was appeared by my uninstaller software.

Then I clean my System Drive by using CCleaner, and restart my PC.

After restarting I try to install MySQL and this time I install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribution Package manually. Set my port number, Password, Service name very carefully.
And this time everything done successfully.

Now I could work in my MySQL Workbench .